# Bootstrap carousel make text appearing letter by letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel for the slider , on each slide there is some text over it.

I would like that text over the slides to aappear letter by letter.

I have almost solved it..

But there are 2 issues

1. On first slide the text doesn't come up at all
2. If the user goes to some other tab on the browser means if the current window is not in focus ,then everything gets messed up.

**[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/termi1290/Lbasa2jh/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="block-wrap">
          <div id="js-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Chania">
                <div class="caption">

                  <div class="mystring hide">companies with Inbound Marketing</div>
                  <h4>We help <div class="demo-txt"></div> </h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Chania">
                <div class="caption">
                <div class="mystring hide">companies with Inbound Marketing</div>

                  <h4>We help  <div class="demo-txt "></div> </h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Flower">
                <div class="caption">
                <div class="mystring hide">2companies with Inbound Marketing</div>

                  <h4>We help <div class="demo-txt"></div> </h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Flower">
                <div class="caption">
                <div class="mystring hide">3companies with Inbound Marketing</div>

                  <h4>We help <div class="demo-txt"></div> </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="overlay-effect"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </main>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
     $('#js-carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    });

     $('#js-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
      var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) { 
        if (index < message.length) { 
          $(target).append(message[index++]); 
          setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
        } 
      }                 
       var str = $(this).find(".active .mystring").html();
          $('.active .demo-txt').html("");         
          showText(".active .demo-txt", str, 0, 100);          
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `settimeout` use `setInterval` function. Also use `clearInterval` to clear schedular when a new slide begin. (I think this is your second problem.)

Here is your target js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#js-carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    });
    var handler;
    var interval = 5000;
    var index = 0;
    function showText(target, message, index, interval) { 
        if (index < message.length) { 
            $(target).append(message[index]); 
        }
    }

    function iteration() {
        if(handler){
            clearInterval(handler);
        }
        index = 0;
        var str = $(this).find(".active .mystring").html();
        $('.active .demo-txt').html("");
        showText(".active .demo-txt", str, index++, 100);         
        handler = setInterval(function(){
            showText(".active .demo-txt", str, index++, 100);
        }, 100);
     }

     //on each carousel slide change: 
     $('#js-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', iteration);
     //start immediately for your first problem:
     iteration.bind($('#js-carousel'))();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

*It's because your function is inside the slide event. At starting, the carousel doesn't slide...*

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbasa2jh/5/

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) { 
    if (index < message.length) { 
          $(target).append(message[index++]); 
          setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
        } 
      };

    $('#js-carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    });

       var str0 = $(this).find(".active .mystring").html();
       $('.active .demo-txt').html("");         
       showText(".active .demo-txt", str0, 0, 100);    

     $('#js-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

       var str = $(this).find(".active .mystring").html();
          $('.active .demo-txt').html("");         
          showText(".active .demo-txt", str, 0, 100);          
     });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for responding so fast ! this seems to fix first issue 1 . But did you also notice if the current window is not in focus ,then everything gets messed up.

Comment: Can it be the reason that may carousal doesn't stop and js for tletter by letter keeps working or vice-versa?  I don't know I am struck .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ' current window is not in focus' :-/

Comment: like if you run your fiddle! everything will work fine ,,But if you change the tab in browser or you switch from chrome to firefox or vice versa , or you minimize  browser & go to desktop for a while and then come back again to your fiddle link then , you will see all the text gets messed up

Comment: i hope i am making sense?

Comment: i am on windows , chrome & firefox  , may be issue with windows?                                                                    http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1157568/3e2c3c3d2caf4f3ba114199bbb556a70

Answer (score 2):

The timer can be tricky when the tab goes inactive. I moved code around and cleared the timeout to make sure the timeout is clean when starting a new slide.

I noticed an issue (not always) when switching back from a different tab is that the carousel actually moves to next slide quicker than 5 second causing the text to be incomplete.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLwm58Ln/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#js-carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
  });

  var showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {
    if (index < message.length) {      
       $(target).append(message[index++]);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
           showText(target, message, index, interval);
        }, interval);
    }
  }, timer;
  
  //First time, this triggers right away instead of waiting for the slide to move
  showText(".active .demo-txt", $('#js-carousel').find(".active .mystring").html(), 0, 100);
  
  $('#js-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    //clear any messed up timeout from prev slide
    clearTimeout(timer);
    //clear message that may be incomplete from the previous text animation
    $('.prevActive').removeClass('prevActive').html('');
    var str = $(this).find(".active .mystring").html();
    $('.active .demo-txt').addClass('prevActive').html("");
 showText(".active .demo-txt", str, 0, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner .overlay-effect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.carousel-inner .caption {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 5%;
}

.carousel-inner .caption h1,
.carousel-inner .caption h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.carousel-inner .caption h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.carousel-inner .caption h2 {
  font-size: 44px;
}

.carousel-inner .demo-txt {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ec8422;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block-wrap">
      <div id="js-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Chania">
            <div class="caption">

              <div class="mystring hide">companies with Inbound Marketing</div>
              <h4>We help <div class="demo-txt"></div> </h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Chania">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="mystring hide">companies with Inbound Marketing</div>

              <h4>We help  <div class="demo-txt "></div> </h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Flower">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="mystring hide">2companies with Inbound Marketing</div>

              <h4>We help <div class="demo-txt"></div> </h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="Flower">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="mystring hide">3companies with Inbound Marketing</div>

              <h4>We help <div class="demo-txt"></div> </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay-effect"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: buddy thanks a lot for help !!! Actuall the above answer already solved my answer, i was testing with it!!1  If i could share my points i would have distributed amond all the answers   ..  :)    +1 for your answer